# Consuming RabbitMQ message in controller

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm currently learning about services, API's and AMQP messaging sistem, RabbitMQ to be precise, and I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8pMwciZ95U&t=128s) about RabbitMQ messaging. I got everything working, but I wanted to change some things in my project. I want to invoke publisher and consumer scripts from my routes and controllers, instead of typing them in my terminal (*php src/publisher.php* or *php src/consumer.php*)

For the start, I created two routes:

```
 Route::get('/send-message', 'ServiceAController@index');
 Route::get('/receive-message', 'ServiceBController@index');
```

First route (send-message) is used to send HTTP requests as a message to RabbitMQ, and that's done through Postman POST request, where I insert parameters that I need. Controller for this route works perfectly and it looks like this:

```
public function index(Request $request){
    //Returning status 200 and sending message if amount is in range
    if( (-100000000  <= $request->amount )  &&  ($request->amount <= 100000000 )){
        //Sending message to RabbitMQ
        $amount = $request->amount;
        $currency = $request->currency;

        //Saving request data to variable to publish it
        $messageContent = json_encode([
            'amount' => $amount * 100,
            'currency' => $currency,
        ]);

        //Sending broker message
        $host = 'secret';
        $port = 5672;
        $user = 'secret';
        $pass = 'secret';
        $vhost = 'secret';
        $exchange = 'balance';
        $queue = 'local_balance';

        $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection($host, $port, $user, $pass, $vhost);
        $channel = $connection->channel();
        /*
            The following code is the same both in the consumer and the producer.
            In this way we are sure we always have a queue to consume from and an
                exchange where to publish messages.
        */
        /*
            name: $queue
            passive: false
            durable: true // the queue will survive server restarts
            exclusive: false // the queue can be accessed in other channels
            auto_delete: false //the queue won't be deleted once the channel is closed.
        */
        $channel->queue_declare($queue, false, true, false, false);
        /*
            name: $exchange
            type: direct
            passive: false
            durable: true // the exchange will survive server restarts
            auto_delete: false //the exchange won't be deleted once the channel is closed.
        */
        $channel->exchange_declare($exchange, 'direct', false, true, false);
        $channel->queue_bind($queue, $exchange);
        $messageBody = $messageContent;
        $message = new AMQPMessage($messageBody, ['content_type' => 'application/json', 'delivery_mode' => AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT]);
        $channel->basic_publish($message, $exchange);
        $channel->close();
        $connection->close();

        //Returning json response of HTTP payload
        $response = json_encode([
            'amount' => +number_format($amount, 2, '.', ''),
            'currency' => $currency,
        ]);
        return $response;
    }else{
        //Returning status 400 if amount is not in acceptable range
        abort(400, 'Amount is not in acceptable range'); //Returning code 400 if condition isn't met
    }
}
```

But my **problem** starts when I put my consumer code in ServiceBController, in the same way I did it for the previous one. My ServiceBController looks like this:

```
public function index(){

    $host = 'secret';
    $port = 5672;
    $user = 'secret';
    $pass = 'secret';
    $vhost = 'secret';
    $exchange = 'balance';
    $queue = 'local_balance';

    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection($host, $port, $user, $pass, $vhost);
    $channel = $connection->channel();
    /*
        The following code is the same both in the consumer and the producer.
        In this way we are sure we always have a queue to consume from and an
            exchange where to publish messages.
    */
    /*
        name: $queue
        passive: false
        durable: true // the queue will survive server restarts
        exclusive: false // the queue can be accessed in other channels
        auto_delete: false //the queue won't be deleted once the channel is closed.
    */
    $channel->queue_declare($queue, false, true, false, false);
    /*
        name: $exchange
        type: direct
        passive: false
        durable: true // the exchange will survive server restarts
        auto_delete: false //the exchange won't be deleted once the channel is closed.
    */
    $channel->exchange_declare($exchange, 'direct', false, true, false);
    $channel->queue_bind($queue, $exchange);
    /**
     * @param AMQPMessage $message
     */
    function process_message(AMQPMessage $message){
        $messageBody = json_decode($message->body);
        $amount = $messageBody->amount;
        $currency = $messageBody->currency;

        file_put_contents('C:/xampp/htdocs/nsoft/data' . '.json', $message->body);

        $message->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
    }
    /*
        queue: Queue from where to get the messages
        consumer_tag: Consumer identifier
        no_local: Don't receive messages published by this consumer.
        no_ack: Tells the server if the consumer will acknowledge the messages.
        exclusive: Request exclusive consumer access, meaning only this consumer can access the queue
        nowait:
        callback: A PHP Callback
    */
    $consumerTag = 'local.consumer';
    $channel->basic_consume($queue, $consumerTag, false, false, false, false, 'process_message');
    /**
     * @param \PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel $channel
     * @param \PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection $connection
     */
    function shutdown($channel, $connection){
        $channel->close();
        $connection->close();
    }

    register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $channel, $connection);

    while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
        $channel->wait();
    }
}
```

After invoking it in Postman, with a get request, I get the following error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in file C:\xampp\htdocs\nsoft\vendor\php-amqplib\php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO.php on line 227.

I've been stuck with this error for a few days now, and seems like I can't find a solution, so I need someones help. What I'm I doing wrong here? For the reference, the same consumer script works when I put it as a separate file (*src/consumer.php*) and when I call it through my terminal. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I can advice to you is to use RabbitMQ queue driver for Laravel:

https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq

With RabbitMQ server you can manage all the messages throught the Laravel's native queue system. Only thing (after configuration) you need to do is to run: `php artisan queue:work` in the console.

There are few ways to use handle the queue working instant. For example you can use Supervisor:

http://supervisord.org/

Comment: thank you for your feedback, I will look into this. So the way I did it is not the right way? I just needed those functionalities to work.

Comment: It's not that that your way isn't right. Think about using more complex and tested solution. The way you're trying to do is already implemented do you don't need to figure it out from The begining.

Answer (score -1):

change the value for the param `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`

```
max_execution_time = 360   ;Execution time in seconds
```

Comment: that didn't do anything, instead of extending execution time to 360, still got the same error and my message gets **Unacked**. I feel that the error could be in the way I'm calling/invoking the consumer in Postman, maybe it shouldn't be done in the way I'm doing it.